# How to get the execution plan of a prepared statement work?

Tags: postgresql, rdbms, sql-execution-plan

How does the DBMS (postgres in my case) deals with execution plan and prepared statement.

The parameters of a query can have a huge impact on the execution plan, mainly due to data statistics.

It might prefer in certain cases use an index if the data is well distributed but for a particular value prefer a sequential scan because the parameter is not discriminant (usually when the parameter matches > 10% of table rows)

I am wondering if prepared statement are always a good way to improve performances or if it more a kind of "best effort"

Thanks in advance

**Edit**: my concern is about running frequently the same query, but with other parameters that could need to vary the execution plan. It is quite hard to measure the performance gain of prepared statement vs always have the most accurate execution plan

Answer (score 1):

A prepared statement is a GREAT way to make the same simple query run over and over faster. For instance, something like

```
insert into table values ($1,$2,$3);
```

OTOH it is NOT a great way to make big ugly complex reporting queries run faster, where the data set may change based on what's in the where clause.

The whole point of prepared queries is to save the somewhat expensive step of query planning over and over. For the simple insert listed above, run 1,000 times, the cost of planning adds up.

OTOH for a big complex reporting query, the planning time is inconsequential. Most big reporting queries etc take seconds to minutes to even hours to run. The planning time, measured in milliseconds, is not worth worrying about here.